# Keeping the scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a shoutbox and I want to keep the scroll to bottom same as IM windows.

My html is

```
<div id="shoutContainer">
            <table id="shoutbox">
                <tbody>
                      <!-- shouts here -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
```

My css

```
#shoutContainer {
    height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If its not possible through html and css. Can we achieve this in raw javascript? because I am not using any framework

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever an item is added, do the following:

```
document.getElementById('shoutContainer').scrollTop = 10000;
// or some other big number
```

edited

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this with CSS alone, but here's a great jQuery solution: [Ajaxdaddy shoutbox](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-shoutbox.html).

Here is a free shout box service to keep your client happy:

[Free shoutboxes](http://www.freeshoutbox.net/).

I just made one to make sure it's ok, [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/FNnmN/).

Comment: Can we have without framework? I am not allowed to use a framework.