# How can I tell a scrollbar to always start at the bottom with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if it's possible to use CSS only here, but I'm hoping it is.  I have a chat box like this:

[image]

I'd like for the scrollbar to always start at the bottom if there is any vertical overflow, without involving any animations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653233/keeping-the-scroll-to-bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need JavaScript. `objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight`

Unless the content is in an iframe. In which case you could make the url of the iframe "page.php#bottom" and add `<div id="bottom"></div>`